# while running airflow version command on linux showing error traceback, please help me

Tags: python-3.x, linux, airflow

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/hduser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from airflow import settings
  File "/home/hduser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 37, in <module>
    from airflow.configuration import AIRFLOW_HOME, WEBSERVER_CONFIG, conf  # NOQA F401
  File "/home/hduser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 1007, in <module>
    conf.validate()
  File "/home/hduser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 209, in validate
    self._validate_config_dependencies()
  File "/home/hduser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 246, in _validate_config_dependencies
    raise AirflowConfigException(f"error: cannot use sqlite version < {min_sqlite_version}")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: error: cannot use sqlite version < 3.15.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install sqlite3 version >= 3.15.0.
To check the current version you can run

```
python -c "import sqlite3; print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)"
```

in the same environment as you ran `airflow version`.

Comment: @sunilkumarreddy which GNU/Linux distro do you use?

Comment: centos linux version 7

Comment: don't mean to be rude, but have you tried searching for "centos 7 upgrade sqlite"?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I upgraded sqlite version to 3.35.4. while intializing db showing error `AttributeError: columns`